# Which scriptures talk about casting and removing spells?

Tags: scripture

I remember reading that Atharva Veda containing mantras for spells.

Mantra (मन्त्र) in the sense of

> a mystical verse or magical formula (sometimes personified), incantation, charm, spell (esp. in modern times employed by the Śāktas to acquire superhuman powers;)

Comment: Atharva veda has this. but a word of caution - the mantras have to be pronounced exactly; if mispronounced they can have the exact opposite effect. This question is a duplicate. btw, mantras are sounds, or vibrations. Sanskrit is entirely composed of mantras. The definition you provide is misleading.